# htaccess redirect to mobile site only working on the homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have created a redirect that redirects the user to the mobile site when on a mobile device, however it is only working on the homepage? How do I get it to work for all pages?

This is the code I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check for mime types commonly accepted by mobile devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^ https://m.my-website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I am a novice when it comes to .htaccess files so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$` line

Answer (score 2):

As anubhava sir already mentioned about removing the condition + I am trying to improve your code too, have your htaccess in following way:

```
Rewriteengine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} (?:text\/vnd\.wap\.wml)|(?:application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://m.my-website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R,L]
```

I have added `NE` flag(check documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#page-header for more details on it) to your redirect rule, then I have created non-capturing group to segregate your patterns check in your condition check part, to make it much clearer.